# How to make a centered navbar HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to create a navbar that has my page links centered in the middle with a logo aligned to the left side and another link aligned to the right side. With my current setup, what would I have to do to create that?

```css
#trans-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#trans-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#trans-nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #666 url(nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
#trans-nav li:hover {
  background-position: 0 -40px;
}
#trans-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#trans-nav li a:hover {
  color: #0F0
}
#trans-nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 8em;
  background: #63867f;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
#trans-nav li ul li {
  float: none;
  position: static;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background: none;
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#trans-nav li ul li a {
  background: #666
}
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #666
}
#trans-nav {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<ul id="trans-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Widgets</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Thingamabobs</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Doohickies</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Info</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example of what you're looking for. Maybe take some pointers from it.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <span>Logo</span>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="other">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {}

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.logo,
.nav,
.other {
  float: left;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.logo {
  width: 25%;
  background: #333;
}

.logo span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

.nav {
  width: 50%;
  background: #666;
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

.other {
  width: 25%;
  background: #999;
}

.other a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {

  .logo, .nav, .other {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kds5w23m/1/)